# Trying to understand/prove an equivalence of the definition of a pair of "jointly normal" rvs

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

It is well-known that the following is one of the equivalent definitions of "jointly normal":

**Definition 1.** Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be a random vector. Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are said to be *jointly normal* if and only if there exist real numbers  $\mu_1, \mu_2, \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k, \beta_1,\ldots, \beta_k$ and independent random variables $Z_1,Z_2, \ldots , Z_k$ (for some $k \geq 1$), each of which has a standard normal distribution, such that

$$
\begin{align*} X & = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i Z_i + \mu_1 \\
 Y & = \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i Z_i + \mu_2. 
\end{align*}  $$

I think (not entirely sure, correct me if I'm wrong) the following statement ("Definition 2") is equivalent to Definition 1:

**Definition 2.** Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be a random vector. Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are said to be *jointly normal* if and only if there exist real numbers  $ \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k, \beta_1,\ldots, \beta_k$ and independent random variables $Z_1,Z_2, \ldots , Z_k$ (for some $k \geq 1$), each of which has a normal distribution, such that

$$
\begin{align*} X & = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i Z_i  \\
 Y & = \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i Z_i. 
\end{align*}  $$

Notice that, in contrast to Definition 1, in Definition 2 the rvs $Z_i$ need *not* necessarily have the standard normal distribution (any normal is fine).

I want to show the equivalence of the two definitions given above. It is obvious that Definition 2 implies Definition 1. I have not been able to show that Definition 1 implies Definition 2; I do have some partial results, namely under the extra assumptions that $k=2$ and $\alpha_1 \beta_2 - \alpha_2 \beta_1 \neq 0$ I managed to prove it. Of course the general idea is to "absorb" the $\mu$s inside the rvs, but unfortunately I haven't been able to do it. C**an someone point out a proof or sketch?** Thanks a lot. **Alternatively, if someone knows a reference where this is shown, that would also be great!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have equivalence of the two definitions provided that any of the $Z_i$ in Definition 2 is allowed to be a degenerate normal variable with standard deviation zero, i.e., a constant.  Notice that under Definition 1 it's possible to achieve a jointly normal distribution $(X,Y)$ where both $X$ and $Y$ are nonzero constants. But this is never possible if every $Z_i$ in Definition 2 is required to be nondegenerate normal.

So given that we can take $Z_{k+1}=1$ in Definition 2, the proof that Definition 1 implies Definition 2 is trivial.

Comment: Thank you. In general, a degenerate rv is considered normal in this context, right? E.g., the theorem that a random vector is jointly normal iff any linear combination of its components is normal, also presupposes this I believe. (Indeed, if we e.g. were to pick all coefficients to zero, then we'd get that the constant 0 r.v. would have to have the normal distribution.)

Comment: Yes, under every definition of "jointly normal" that I know of, the (univariate) components of a jointly normal random vector are allowed to be constant.

Comment: @herbhofsterd Since the problem seems to be solved, you might want to [mark one of the answers as accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark (✓) icon next to the answer on the left. Doing so will mark the question as answered, and will also award both you and the author of the answer a few reputation points.  Once you gain enough rep (15 points is enough), you can also vote up any answers you find helpful.